# CakePHP How to get data from csv file after upload

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I created a form with input type `file`, button submit to access to a function in controller, the problem is I can't get data from that file.
in controller when I call :

```html
function displayAll() {

 $adherents = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 prd($adherents);
}
```

I found this error

> Undefined index: file [APP\controllers\adherents.php, line 36]

and this is the view:

```html
<h2>Upload filer</h2>
<br>
<fieldset class="pano bleu">

<?php echo $this->Form->create('adherentsSuph', array('action'=>'displayAll'));?>

 <?php
  echo $this->Form->input('file', array('type' => 'file'));
  echo $bouton->block(array(
            'cancel'=>array('action'=>'index'),
            'submit'=>array('id'=>'addAdherentFile')
    ));
  echo $this->Form->end();?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt or lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Comment: I'm working under CakePHP 1.3

Answer (score 1):

Add `'type' => 'file'` to  your form options like this:

`<?php echo $this->Form->create('adherentsSuph', array('action'=>'displayAll', 'type' => 'file')); ?`>

Check if is a valid request and a valid file, then use `file()` to read the entire file into an array and loop it.

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    if (is_file($this->data['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        $file = file($this->data['file']['tmp_name']);
        foreach ($file as $key => $row) {
            var_dump($row); die;
        }
    }
}
```

**See also:**

- [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)
- [is_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)
- [Form > Options > Type](https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#options-type)
- [Field naming convention](https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#field-naming-convention)

> Debug `$this->data` to check if you need to change `$this->data['file']` to `$this->data['adherentsSuph']['file']`

Comment: first Thank you forr helping, but it does not work I found this error:  Undefined property: AdherentsSuphsController::$request                Fatal error: Call to a member function is() on null in C:\wamp64\www\project\controllers\adherents_suphs_controller.php on line 35

Comment: I updated the answer for CakePHP 1.3 now, check again please.

Comment: always $this->data is empty !! I tried to display all data like this prd($this->data)  ===> no result

Answer (score 0):

Your question is of poor quality since you are giving incomplete code. I will try to help you anyway.

Please check the following things:

1. Are you using the CakePHP [FormHelper](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html)?
2. If so make sure you initialize the `Form` with `'type' => 'file'` (see [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-file-inputs)).
3. Finally check, what you get in `$this->request->data` in your `Controller`.